# How can I use Jabber with OTR on IOS?

Tags: ios, encryption, jabber

I would like to use Jabber with OTR Encoding on my iPad. Which clients are supporting this?

Apps already tried:

- [ChatSecure](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chatsecure-encrypted-secure/id464200063?mt=8) doesn't seem to work with XMPP.
- [IM+ Pro](http://www.shape.ag/en/products/details.php?product=im&platform=none) is [not recommended](http://forum.ifun.de/threads/55870-Suche-jabber-xmpp-client-mit-%28gut-funktionierender%29-OTR-Unterst%C3%BCtzung).
- [Trillian](https://www.trillian.im/) has no OTR support.

Comment: The referenced page is six months old, are you sure the apps tested there haven't changed in the meantime?

Comment: I just tried it, and couldn't manage to connect to my jabber account with ChatSecure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ChatSecure](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chatsecure-encrypted-secure/id464200063?mt=8) works now:

Just enter Username and password and leave the other settings default:

[image]

In chat you can activate OTR at the top right corner

Comment: Although the program has to be started to get the messages, this is noch the perfect solution yet

Comment: Doesnt work with some required servers xmpp.

Comment: @Hmm: please clarify what you tried and what didn't work? Usually it works fine with XMPP

Comment: ChatSecure also doesn't work for me (error message with the jabber.de SSL certificate, no way to bypass it, registration also errors out). There really are no other jabber clients on ios?

Answer (score -1):

use pgp/gpg + vpn. ios - it not hidden os

Comment: Could you elaborate? "not hidden os", what do you mean?

Answer (score -2):

For iOS, I know I use PGP. Maybe this can help you.

Comment: How do you configure and/or what app do you use in order to use PGP & Jabber?